Characterization of flabby sheaves by Cech cohomology
Let $(\mathsf C,\tau)$ be a site, and assume that $\mathsf C$ admits finite fibered products. For any object $U$ in $\mathsf C$, denote by $\mathcal J_U$ the category of coverings of $U$ and refinement maps.
Reading Tamme's Introduction to Etale Cohomology, I see that an abelian sheaf $F$ on $(\mathsf C,\tau)$ is flabby if and only if $H^n(U,F)=0$ for all $U$ in $\sf C$ and all $n\gt 0$ (chapter I, 3.5.3).
From the papers of my course it appears that, at least assuming $\sf C$ closed under finite fibered products, there is a characterization of flabby sheaves using Cech cohomology: an abelian sheaf $F$ is flabby if and only if $\check{H^n}(U,F)=0$ for all $U$ in $\sf C$ and all $n\gt 0$.
One direction is trivial, so I'm interested in proving this: any abelian sheaf $F$ on $(\mathsf C,\tau)$, such that $\check{H^n}(U,F)=0$ for all $U$ in $\sf C$ and all $n\gt 0$, is flabby.
It suffices to prove the following:
Let $U$ in $\sf C$ and let $F$ be an abelian sheaf on $(\mathsf C,\tau)$ such that $\check {H^n}(U,F)=0$ for $n\gt 0$. Then, for any covering $\mathcal U$ of $U$ and all $n\gt 0$, holds $\check {H^n}(\mathcal U,F)=0$.
Let $F\to I_0\to I_1\to\cdots$ be an injective resolution of $F$ as a presheaf: $\check {H^n}(\mathcal U,F)$ is computed via homology from the complex $\check {H^0}(\mathcal U,I_0)\to\check {H^0}(\mathcal U,I_1)\to\cdots$ and, as the functor $\operatorname{colim}: [\mathcal J_U^{op},\mathsf{Ab}]\to\sf Ab$  is exact, it commutes with homology. So one can compute $\check {H^n}( U,F)$ via homology from the complex below. $$\operatorname{colim}_{\mathcal U\in \mathcal J_U}\check {H^0}(\mathcal U,I_0)\to\operatorname{colim}_{\mathcal U\in \mathcal J_U}\check {H^0}(\mathcal U,I_1)\to\cdots$$
In our case, the latter complex is exact and we need to show that the complex relative to every $\mathcal U$ is exact. Hence it is not sufficient that $\mathrm {colim}$ is exact, it should also reflect exactness.
For example, if an exact functor is faithful I think it reflects exactness, but I don't think that the colimit over $\mathcal J_U$ is a faithful functor in general. Maybe I need to use in some way that the $I_n$ are injective presheaves? Thanks a lot for any suggestion

I’m not sure how much of this applies in your setting, but how about working by induction over $n >0$ and considering an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow F \rightarrow G \rightarrow H\rightarrow 0$ with $G$ injective? Starting with either side of the equivalence to prove, the sequence $0 \rightarrow H^0(U,F) \rightarrow H^0(U,G) \rightarrow H^0(U,H) \rightarrow 0$ is exact, right?

For the case of sheaves on a space, I can prove that vanishing of Cech cohomology in every positive degree over every open subset entails flabbiness ... using the Grothendieck spectral sequence comparing Cech with derived sheaf cohomology. I wouldn't know if that argument could still make sense for sheaves on a site

@FShrike it depends on the definition of flabbiness.. If even on spaces the definition of flabby sheaf $F$ is that $H^n(\mathcal U,F)=0$ for every covering $\mathcal U$ and any $n\gt 0$  maybe it could make sense
